# SQL calculation - I want to make the beginning QTY this month the ending QTY from the previous month

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have the following result set where the first row is correct.  For the rest of the rows I would like the Beginning QTY for each month to equal the Ending QTY from the previous month.

[image: Result Set]

Here's the code:

```sql
   DECLARE @BegValue AS INT
    SELECT @BegValue =
                SUM(
                CASE
                    WHEN ItemCode = '001'
                    AND WarehouseCode = '000'
                    AND TransactionDate < '01/01/2021' THEN TransactionQty END)
                    FROM MAS_SAV.dbo.IM_ItemTransactionHistory
    SELECT
           ItemCode
          ,WarehouseCode
          ,MONTH(CAST(TransactionDate AS DATE)) as 'Month Num'
          ,FORMAT(CAST(TransactionDate AS DATE), 'MMM') AS 'Month'
          ,@BegValue AS 'Beginning QTY'
          ,FORMAT(SUM(CASE WHEN TransactionCode = 'SO' THEN TransactionQTY END), '#,###')  AS 'QTY Sold'
          ,FORMAT(SUM(CASE WHEN TransactionCode = 'PO' THEN TransactionQTY END), '#,###') AS 'QTY Received'
          ,FORMAT(SUM(CASE WHEN TransactionCode = 'SI' OR TransactionCode = 'II' THEN TransactionQTY END), '#,###') AS 'QTY Issued'
          ,FORMAT(SUM(CASE WHEN TransactionCode = 'IT' THEN TransactionQTY END), '#,###') AS 'QTY Transfer'
          ,FORMAT(SUM(CASE WHEN TransactionCode = 'IP' THEN TransactionQTY END), '#,###') AS 'QTY Adjusted'
          ,FORMAT(SUM(TransactionQty) + @BegValue, '#,###')  AS 'Ending QTY'
    FROM MAS_SAV.dbo.IM_ItemTransactionHistory
    WHERE ItemCode = '001' and TransactionDate >= '01/01/2021' and WarehouseCode = '000'
    GROUP BY
           ItemCode
          ,WarehouseCode
          ,MONTH(CAST(TransactionDate AS DATE))
          ,FORMAT(CAST(TransactionDate AS DATE), 'MMM')
    ORDER BY 3
```

Comment: Sounds like you want a windowed aggregate.

Comment: [Edit] the question and provide a [example], i.e. the `CREATE` statements of the tables or other objects involved (paste the **text**, don't use images, don't link to external sites), `INSERT` statements for sample data (dito) and the desired result with that sample data in tabular text format.

Comment: A standard `LAG(...) OVER (ORDER BY MONTH(CAST(TransactionDate AS DATE)))`  works does it not?

Answer (score 0):

This should get you what you need:

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE
(
    ItemCode       VARCHAR(10)
    ,WarehouseCode VARCHAR(10)
    ,MonthNum      VARCHAR(10)
    ,Month         VARCHAR(10)
    ,BeginningQTY  VARCHAR(10)
    ,QTYSold       VARCHAR(10)
    ,QTYReceived   VARCHAR(10)
    ,QTYIssued     VARCHAR(10)
    ,QTYTransfer   VARCHAR(10)
    ,QTYAdjusted   VARCHAR(10)
    ,EndingQTY     VARCHAR(10)
);
INSERT INTO @Table
(
    ItemCode
    ,WarehouseCode
    ,MonthNum
    ,Month
    ,BeginningQTY
    ,QTYSold
    ,QTYReceived
    ,QTYIssued
    ,QTYTransfer
    ,QTYAdjusted
    ,EndingQTY
)
SELECT '001','000','1','Jan','4271','-535','2400','-900','-233',NULL,'5003'
UNION ALL SELECT '001','000','2','Feb','4271','-325',NULL,'140','-255',24,'3855'
UNION ALL SELECT '001','000','3','Mar','4271','-531',NULL,'-600','-1608',NULL,'1532'
UNION ALL SELECT '001','000','4','Apr','4271','-559','1200','-786','-450',NULL,'3676'
UNION ALL SELECT '001','000','5','May','4271','-95', NULL,'-400',NULL,NULL,'3776';

SELECT  c.ItemCode
        ,c.WarehouseCode
        ,c.MonthNum
        ,c.Month
        ,ISNULL(t.EndingQTY, c.BeginningQTY) AS BeginningQTY
        ,c.QTYSold
        ,c.QTYReceived
        ,c.QTYIssued
        ,c.QTYTransfer
        ,c.QTYAdjusted
        ,c.EndingQTY
FROM    @Table AS c
        LEFT OUTER JOIN @Table AS t ON t.ItemCode = c.ItemCode
                                       AND t.WarehouseCode = c.WarehouseCode
                                       AND t.MonthNum + 1 = c.MonthNum;
```